# Enter the sequence number of the playing card (from 0 to 35) and determine the suit and dignity of the card

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was able to write only 36 switches, how to shorten the code?You cannot use loops or other functions,only if and switch.(do not write 36 case or 36 if, you can do less).

Comment: A lookup table?

Comment: I don't know what you mean(

Comment: no it can't be used

Comment: @ulyahasanova Please explain more about the problem. what do you mean by sequence number of if you are talking about some puzzle then describe it.

Comment: the user enters from 0 to36 any number.The program should display the suit and the sequence number of the card, while using only switch and if

Comment: Is there a rule for determining suit and dignity of a number?

Comment: in the task is not written like this

Comment: The question is completely unclear. How does the card deck look like? 4 suites? So 9 cards each? What is the expected output? Normally such things can be simply calculated with an integer division and the modulo operator. Then, no ````if```` is needed. Please give more details

Comment: just need to solve it with less switch or if or both

Comment: Yes, 4 suits of 9 cards each,so it turns out.I also think here you also need to apply modulo division

Comment: I made 4 switch in everyone on 9 cases and it is incorrect.How to make it so that after 9 it switches to the first?

Comment: Are you counting from 0? Then it should be like 0 to 8 for the first 9 cards, and so forth.

Comment: Sorry about my first comment, I meant number 8 if you meant 0 to 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the cards are represented in a certain order, like this:

```
input   0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 9 10 11 ... 33 34 35 
suite   0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 1 1  1  ... 3  3  3
dignity 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 0 1  2  ... 6  7  8
```

where dignity 0 means a 6 probably and dignity 6, 7, 8 would be Queen, King and Ass (we just start indexing at zero to keep it easy)

Then you can use

```
int suite = input / 9;
int dignity = input % 9;
```

Then you can use a switch to print out the right values (if that's even required):

```
std::cout << "dignity is ";

switch(dignity)
{
     case 0: std::cout << "6"; break; //the dignity of the first card 
     case 1: std::cout << "7"; break;
     // ...
     case 6: std::cout << "Queen"; break;
     case 7: std::cout << "King"; break;
     case 8: std::cout << "Ass"; break;
}

std::cout << "suite is ";

switch(suite)
{
     case 0: std::cout << "...."; break; // name of the first suite.
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let suite be from 0 to 3 and dignity from 0 to 8.

```
int x{0};
do
{
    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 35: ";
    cin >> x;
} while (x < 0 || x > 35);

int suite{x / 9}, diginity{0}, subtract{0};
for (int i{suite}; i > 0; --i)
{
    subtract += 9;
}
diginity = x - subtract;

cout << "Suit: " << suite << endl;
cout << "Dignity: " << diginity << endl;
```

The greater x is, the greater it will be subtracted by subtract, resulting in a number between 0 and 8.